# How to update an entry inside a nested map in elixir

Tags: elixir

I want to update an entry in a heavy nested map. for example, in the below map I want to update city to "Noida". So how can I do that using library provided method? I know that there is a method get_in(map, [:key,...]) which is an easy method to fetch the value. Is there any similar kind of method for update?

```
input = %{
  name: "ashish",
  address: %{city: "delhi", country: "IN"}
}

expectation = %{
  name: "ashish",
  address: %{city: "noida", country: "IN"}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I find [this link](https://dockyard.com/blog/2016/02/01/elixir-best-practices-deeply-nested-maps) useful. The method I was looking for is [`Kernel.put_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#put_in/3).

```
put_in(input, [:address, :city], "noida")
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, to **update** the nested structure, as stated in the question title, one uses [`Kernel.update_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#update_in/3). Also, the post linked is extremely perfunctory and it does not cover even 10% of `Access` power. Elixir documentation on [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html) is a much better source.